# Assign SVG coordinates based on visibility of other element, using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have 12 circular divs, made up of 3 vertical lines of 4 circles (A, B, C and D).


[Image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v60uI.png)

Only 6 circles will ever be visible at the same time in total, and only 2 circles will ever be visible on each vertical line at the same time (1 red and 1 green), e.g. like this...


[Image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiKSB.png)

I would like to place a blue SVG shape behind these circles, whose coordinates matches the shape of the visible circles, like this:


[Image 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE1o6.png)

Here is my SVG code for the static blue shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 800 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 800 800;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#88C9FF;}
</style>
<polygon class="st0" points="100,217.62 400,97.5 700,215.09 700,559.12 400,702.53 100,702.53 "/>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to make the SVG shape dynamic, and input X and Y coordinates for the shape's points, based on the visibility of the circles, preferably using jQuery or JavaScript ?

I am thinking something along the lines of:

If 'circle-1' is visible, insert 'this' X and Y coordinate as the first SVG point, and so on for each of the 6 circles...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify how the drawing logic is supposed to work. It's not clear what you mean by visible – are you dragging points a kind of drawing canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You want to draw a polygon between new drawn points?

```html
<svg-draw-board></svg-draw-board>
<style>
  svg-draw-board {
    width      : 100vw;
    height     : 180px;
    display    : inline-block;
    background : pink;
    cursor     : pointer;
  }
</style>
<script>
customElements.define('svg-draw-board', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    let polygon=[];
    super()
       .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
       .innerHTML = `<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 800"><polygon fill="blue"></polygon></svg>`;
    this.svg = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('svg');
    this.svg.onclick = (evt) => { // convert clientXY to SVG XY
      let CTM = this.svg.getScreenCTM();
      let x = (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a;
      let y = (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d;
      polygon.push([x,y]);
      this.drawCircle( x, y , evt.ctrlKey ? 50 : 30 );
      this.svg.querySelector("polygon").setAttribute("points", String(polygon.flat()) );
    };
  }
  drawCircle(cx, cy, r, fill = 'red') {
    this.svg.append( this.createSVGElement('circle', { cx, cy, r, fill }) );
  }
  createSVGElement( tag, attrs={} ) {
    const el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',tag);
    Object.entries(attrs).map(([name, val]) => el.setAttribute(name, val));
    return el;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, yes almost exactly this, except triggered by page load. The position of the circles is dynamically determined by my CMS, so I just want a way to automatically draw a polygon which matches their position. The circles can have their own class or IDs, which may help.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, I have multiple (253 total) circles on a page, with conditional visibility controlled by CMS, so that depending on my CMS items' values, a unique set of 23 circles will be visible. I'd like to somehow find which 23 circles are currently visible, and create a polygon which matches their shape.